# How to achieve local transparency of borders in CSS?

Tags: css

[image]

How can I achieve the border effect as shown in the picture?

My previous solution was to use pseudo elements to achieve the effect of a mask layer. But if my background is an image or gradient, it will be difficult to adjust the color of the mask layer. How can I achieve local transparency of the border and directly obtain the background color?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You'll probably have to use an SVG as a background image.

Comment: Something like this might help https://kovart.github.io/dashed-border-generator/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use mask:

```css
.box {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 10px solid;
  border-radius: 999px;
  margin: 10px;
  
  -webkit-mask:
    linear-gradient(#000 0 0) no-repeat
      70% 0/80px 10px, /* 70%: control the position | 80px: control the width | 10px: equal to border thickness */
    linear-gradient(#000 0 0);
  -webkit-mask-composite: xor;
          mask-composite: exclude;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg,pink,lightblue);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box" style="width: 400px"></div>
<div class="box" style="width: auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is possible purely with CSS rules, so my solution would be to create an SVG image and set it as the background image.

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300");
}

div {
  width: 116px;
  height: 46px;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="116" height="46" viewBox="0 0 116 46" fill="none"><path d="M53 3H23C23 3 3 3 3 23C3 43 23 43 23 43H93C93 43 113 43 113 23C113 3 93 3 93 3H83" stroke="black" stroke-width="5"/></svg>');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 999px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div></div>
 </body>
```

Comment: Thank you sincerely for your answer. This question has indeed troubled me for a long time, and SVG is indeed the best way to address it.